# Sitemap with character &

Tags: encoding, utf-8, sitemap

I have a sitemap with urls containing the character `&` so google doesn't accept my sitemap, I tried changing `&` to `&amp;` or `%26`so my sitemap got accepted but when I open my urls **they don't work** properly

Example changing from :

```
http://example.com/categorie.php?section=frui&cat=apple
```

to

```
http://example.com/categorie.php?section=frui&amp;cat=apple
```

Or

```
http://example.com/categorie.php?section=frui%26cat=apple
```

Any issues ?

Comment: Read under the section "Notes": http://www.microsystools.com/products/sitemap-generator/help/xml-sitemap-file-amp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should *not* change `&` to `%26`, since they mean different things: `&` is a separator between different query-components, whereas `%26` means an actual `&` *inside* a query-component. The latter is not what you want.

As for changing to `&amp;` — this is fine. It's true that the URL `http://example.com/categorie.php?section=frui&amp;cat=apple` won't work, but your sitemap doesn't specify that URL! Rather, your sitemap contains the *XML parsed character data* `http://example.com/categorie.php?section=frui&amp;cat=apple`, which means the URL `http://example.com/categorie.php?section=frui&cat=apple`. (In XML PC-data, `&amp;` means "an actual `&` in the data", where — in your case — the data is a URL.)